# ActiveRecord - Finding all records with x number of classifications

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to write an ActiveRecord method that will return all Boats with more than three classifications.

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :captain
  has_many    :boat_classifications
  has_many    :classifications, through: :boat_classifications
end

class Classification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boat_classifications
  has_many :boats, through: :boat_classifications
end

class BoatClassifications < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boat
  belongs_to :classification 
end
```

In general, I'm having trouble finding resources for writing queries on join models in AR. If anyone knows any good resources to help learn complex AR queries, that would be really helpful.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

Comment: I've read that, but can't put together how to implement it to solve this particular problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist `JOIN` the *boats* with the *classifications*. Then you need to `GROUP BY` *boats.id* so then you can `COUNT` how many rows you have grouped for every different boat. Using the `HAVING` allows you to apply that condition over the grouped records. At the end, selects the *boats* as you want.

```
Boat.joins(:classifications).group("boats.id").having("COUNT(*) > 3").select("boats.*")
```